# Asymmetric measure of non-linear dependence/correlation?

Tags: correlation, independence, information-theory, mutual-information

I am definitely not a statistician/mathematician so feel free to tell me I'm an idiot if I am.

As far as I can tell from my Wikipediaing all of the main measures of dependence are symmetric and measure the shared information between dimensions. I am looking for an asymmetric method of measuring dependence.

I mean asymmetric in the sense that f(x,y) might return the degree to which x depends on y where f(y,x) would return the degree to which y depends on x.

I have significant control over what form the data will take so I'm not too worried about exactly how I would handle the n-dimensional stuff right now - I intended to leave that as open as possible so as not to restrict the possibilities. Continuing my previous notation perhaps the possibility to implement f(x,y,z) such that the degree to which x could be determined given y and z is returned.

I'm not confident in my use of terminology so I'll provide an example.

Say I had a bunch of x,y pairs where y=1 when x>0 and y=0 otherwise. Basically a step function. Measuring the degree that y depends on x should give a high output (ideally 1) because y can be entirely determined given x. However the degree to which x depends on y is lower - the output should indicate that a relationship is present but that x cannot be fully determined given y.

Bare in mind that the example provided is a simplification - in the real world I'm interested in doing this with a bunch of different datasets with potentially fairly complex non-linear non-monotonic relationships. I will however have my data in x,y pair form.

I have put together a list of a few non-essential properties that an ideal solution would have.

**Ideal property wishlist:**

- Output between 0, 1
- Computationally cheap
- Capable of handling n-dimensional data
- Relatively easy to implement in a non-specialised software environment

Comment: Asymmetric - in the sense one value of the coefficient for x->y dependency and the other value of it for y->x dependency? What do you mean `Capable of handling n-dimensional data`? - are you going to compare two matrices, not just two vectors of values?

Comment: @ttnphns edits were provided to the main post by the poster to address your question.

Answer (score 3):

The $R^2$ of a multivariate regression model is such an asymmetric measure. The regression model of $Y$ on $X$ leads to a different $R^2$ than the regression model of $X$ on $Y$. This is because the value is computed using the proportion of vertical distance from the mean accounted for by the line of best fit using the conditional mean of $Y$ on $X$ to predict average potential outcomes for $Y$.

EDIT: In the discourse below, it was shown that the $R^2$ may be conserved and "symmetric". The $R^2$ has a particular application and is useful for summarizing high dimensional predictive models. In general, *dependence* is a sophisticated mathematical concept, and you can rarely inform much about the dependence between two variables without making strong (and often untestable) assumptions. I think for conveying aspects of the interrelationship between two variables in an applied setting, the term "association" is much better.

For smaller models, simply using the coefficient and its 95% confidence interval from a linear regression model is sufficient for reporting the *first order trend* in those data. These are well established association measures. Even if the trend is possibly nonlinear, a linear regression model has a coefficient that is taken to be a "rule-of-thumb" difference in outcomes for a unit difference in some regressor. These will necessarily be different for regression models treating a $Y$ variable as an outcome or a regressor. I see models of this form presented often in the literature with as many as 20 adjustment variables in large sample sizes.

Comment: This is not true for simple linear regression with one $Y$ and one $X$, since $R^2$ is simply the square of the correlation coefficient. (I realize you state *multivariate* at the beginning, but then the example given is only two variables.)

Comment: @AndyW You are not correct here. $R^2$ is the *vertical* distance eliminated by predicting using a conditional mean versus a grand mean. Intuitively, these distances will be different if the plot is reflected over the identity line. If you accept proof by code, simply generate two random normal vectors, $X$, and $Y$ and calculate the $R^2$ directly for either regression.

Comment: AdamO - the total sums of squares changes too for $R^2$ (otherwise it would not be restricted to within 0 and 1). Proof by code (in R)! `set.seed(10);x <- rnorm(100); y <- 5*x + rnorm(100);summary(lm(y~x))$r.squared == summary(lm(x~y))$r.squared` Again, it is the same as the squared bivariate correlation, `all.equal(summary(lm(y~x))$r.squared,cor(x,y)^2,summary(lm(x~y))$r.squared)`.

Comment: I thought root mean square error *may* be reasonable for what the OP wants (or other error metrics), but that is not standardized to be within a range of 0-1. Maybe if the data were arbitrarily standardized to be within the 0-1 range to begin with - but I am just guessing now.

Comment: @AndyW thanks for pointing that out. You're right, there's an interesting tidbit that the amount of error "explained" is proportional to the total amount of error in the variable which will be different for $X$ and $Y$. I have some insight to update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define nonsymmetric dependence measure R(X,Y) such that R(X,Y)=0 if and only if Y is independent of X, R(X,Y)=1 if and only if Y is a function of X. X and Y can be vector of random variables, continuous or discrete. An example would be a circle X^2 + Y^2 = 1, where neither X nor Y is a function of the other. Traditional symmetric dependence measures such as mutual information or Hellinger distance produce maximum dependence, but the new measure gives value R(X,Y)=R(Y,X)=0.5. Another example is Y=X^2. Again traditional measures give maximum value, but the new measure gives values R(X,Y)=1, R(Y, X)=0.5. Linear correlation gives 0 in both examples. The measure satisfies a new set of conditions different from Renyi's axioms for symmeyric dependence measures. In the continuous case, the measure is based on copula, thus nonparametric. Please check out my recent work on arXiv: 1502.03850, 1511.02744, 1512.07945 on bivariate, multivariate and discrete nonsymmetric dependence measures.

Here are some more details: The nonsymmetric dependence measure R(X,Y) is defined as distance between the cumulative distribution of Y conditional on X and the unconditional cumulative distribution of Y. It equals zero when the two distributions are the same, which implies Y is independent of X. It takes maximum value when Y is a function of X, or the cumulative distribution of Y conditional on X has a single jump from zero to one. This can be extended to n-dimensions, where R(X1,...,Xn,Y) is defined as distance between the cumulative distribution of Y conditional on X1,...,Xn and the unconditional cumulative distribution of Y.  It takes minimum value (zero) when Y is independent of X1,...,Xn. It takes maximum value when Y is a function of X1,...,Xn.

Comment: We appreciate your interest in our site and willingness to direct attention to your work. But you, of all people, surely are in the best position to provide a brief explanation of what you have accomplished.  Without some such summary, this post is just a tease and contains no useful information for the reader.